# e17 enlightenment on bionic beaver black screen

Tags: bug-reporting, enlightenment

I installed `e17` package from the official repos. First run wizard for enlightenment ran fine, but subsequently, I only getting a black screen after login.

I think debian uses the same pacakges. I just installed e17 in debian 9, and it works fine. So, this has to be an issue specific to ubuntu configuration. How can I fix this? Where can I report the issue ?

Comment: I can't confirm this on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. You did something wrong. Or it may be OpenGL-related. Which video card do you have? Do you use physical hardware or virtual machine? Try to remove e17 configuration with `rm -rf ~/.e` and start from the beginning.

Comment: I have an intel video card. I do have an nvidia card, but I have not installed any proprietary drivers. If I disable compositing, desktop load. But with compositing on, its just black screen